# rounding corners of UIbutton disturbing its width

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have three buttons in which I want to round:

- Top corners of first button
- Bottom corners of second button
- All four corners of third button

I achieved this by the following code:

```
        button1.roundedButton1()
        button2.roundedButton2()
        button3.layer.cornerRadius = 5

extension UIButton {
    func roundedButton1(){
        let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight],
                                     cornerRadii:CGSize(width:5.0, height:5.0))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
       // maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer1
    }

    func roundedButton2(){
        let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight],
                                     cornerRadii:CGSize(width:5.0, height:5.0))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer1
    }
}
```

But the width of my 1st and 2nd button is getting disturbed.

[image]

If I use `button2.layer.cornerRadius = 5` then the width becomes alright. I have searched which code it altering its width but didn't find anything appropriate. And this is the only working solution i found for UIButton.Can anyone tell me why the width of button is changing and how to fix it?

The constraints of button are as follows:

[image]

Comment: add your round code in the `viewDidLayoutSubViewMethod` its possible that your buttons don't have the correct width yet when the method is executed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `UIButton` you can achieve this result by using `UIView` & `UITapGestureRecognizer`

add this extension

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

then create a custom view class

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.roundCorners([.topRight, .topLeft], radius: 5) // you can use .topRight , .topLeft , .bottomRight, .bottomLeft 
    }
}
```

then use the class on your view
[image: refer this]

Hope this will help you